# Googlemaps places Autocomplete by className - JS loop Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, for-loop, google-places-api

I need to add Autocomplete to input fields by ClassName. I got it to work but Google does not sent the Address with Postalcode back.

So I am trying to use addListener to insert the formatted_address on the input field.

In this example the input[i] on the autocomplete.addListener is not working:

```
function initMap() {
 
    var input = $('.my_adresse'); 
    
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i], {
            types: ['address'],
            componentRestrictions: {
                'country': ["de", "ch", "aut"]
            }
        });
        
        
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            $(input[i]).val(place.formatted_address);
        });
    }          
}
```

On this example only the last Element of the loop is working:

```
var input = $('.my_adresse'); 
    
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i], {
            types: ['address'],
            componentRestrictions: {
                'country': ["de", "ch", "aut"]
            }
        }); 
        
        var input_to_change= input[i];

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            $(input_to_change).val(place.formatted_address);
        });
    }          
}
```

Why am I getting just the last element of the loop?
What is the best solution to get the Complete Address with postal code using Google Maps places Autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to address the issue is with function closure, create a `createAutocomplete` function to hold closure on the input and the autocomplete object:

```
  function createAutocomplete(input, index) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
      types: ['address'],
      componentRestrictions: {
        'country': ["de", "ch", "aut"]
      }
    });

    var input_to_change = input;

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
      $(input).val(place.formatted_address);
    });
  }
```

and call that in your loop:

```
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    createAutocomplete(input[i], i);
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wc726n1p/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var input = $('.my_adresse');

  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    createAutocomplete(input[i], i);
  }

  function createAutocomplete(input, index) {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
      types: ['address'],
      componentRestrictions: {
        'country': ["de", "ch", "aut"]
      }
    });

    var input_to_change = input;

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
      if (place != null) {
        $(input).val(place.formatted_address);
        if (place.geometry.location) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: place.geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: "" + index
          });
          bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 70%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div>
    <div id="title">
      Autocomplete search
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" class="my_adresse" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="my_adresse" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="my_adresse" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="my_adresse" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```